# I am using material design switch , but i am not able to select it by default or using jquery

Tags: material-design

Below is the sample html:

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect is-checked " for="distanceUnit">
<input type="checkbox" id="distanceUnit" class="mdl-switch__input "/>
<span class="mdl-switch__label left">{% trans "mi" %}</span>
<span class="mdl-switch__label right">{% trans "km" %}</span>
</label>
```

I get the value of distanceUnit from User Profile. with something like `{{ user.userprofile.distance_unit }}` . But I am not sure how to use this in setting the switch to on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn , It was as easy adding the checked property.
Going through the documentation again , always helps.